# CSV not importing into microsoft access

Tags: excel, csv, ms-access-2010

Hi I have a csv file which displays properly in excel, but when I try to import it into access I get the #NUM! error. Any Ideas? Please and thanks!

Here is a pic of my csv in excel
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnsmN.jpg

Here is a pic of my .accdb in access https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnsmN.jpg

I'd be willing to upload both files if anyone knows of a way to upload files into a link.

Comment: What is the format of columns in csv ?

Comment: What do you mean? How Would I figure this out?

Comment: They're simply strings separated by commas and new lines. When opened in excel it displays as above.

Comment: I got it! I just had to check "First row contains field names" to get it to work. Thanks!